# How can we get the same sequence of columns as a result in DynamoDB query present in the DB?

Tags: python-3.x, collections, boto3, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking for a way to get the boto3 DynamoDB query results(columns), that the way I am inserting into the DB.

My insert operation:

```
DYNAMO_CLIENT.put_item(
            TableName=TABLE_NAME,
            Item={
                "id": {"S": data.id},
                "name": {"S": data.name},
                "account_id": {"S": data.provider_account_id},
                "provider": {"S": data.provider},
                "is_enabled" : {'BOOL':data.enabled)}
           },
)
```

**My Query:**

```
response = table.query(
                IndexName='provider-id-index',
                KeyConditionExpression=Key('provider').eq(provider)
            )
        for item in response["Items"]:
            print(item.values())
```

**Output that I am getting:**

```
{"is_enabled":False, name:"sample","account_id":"12345","id="345","provider":"none"}
```

**Expecting:**

```
{"id="345",name:"sample","account_id":"12345","provider":"none","is_enabled":False}
```

I know the `response["Items"]` returning the list of `dict` objects (its unordered). But I am looking for a way to do it.

I tried with `collections.OrderdDict(item.values()[0])` but no luck.

Any solution on this problem would be appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you willing to maintain the list of keys you used to insert with? If so, that same list might be used to map the returned dicts to expected dicts

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the order of the items in the dictionary. If you need things in a certain order you probably should rethink why that is. If the order is important for something that is out of your control you can always take the result and put the values into a new object that is ordered the way you want. If that order is unique to each item you could store the order in an attribute on the item. Generally speaking, this isn't something you should be concerned with.

Comment: Yes, we can not control the order of dict, but is there a way to query to dynamo that return an OrderdDict..?

Comment: No. The response is just JSON. It doesn't have an order.